# How to build a statement to perform a groupby operation during runtime on a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dynamic-programming

I have a Pandas DataFrame `dfs` and a list `headers`

The list `headers` is assigned the column names of the DataFrame `dfs` during runtime.

For ex, let us consider the list gets assigned with `dfs`'s column names as:

```
["Information_type", "Interface", "Type_of_Interface", "Connection_Mechanism"]
```

I want to perform the below `groupby` and `agg` operation on the DataFrame `dfs`
without explicitly mentioning the column names in the groupby operation i.e. `"Information_type": " ".join` , `"Interface": " ".join` , `"Type_of_Interface": " ".join` , `"Connection_Mechanism": " ".join`:

```
dfs[0]=dfs[0].groupby("grp").agg({"Information_type": " ".join, "Interface": " ".join, "Type_of_Interface": " ".join, "Connection_Mechanism": " ".join})
```

Basically write `"Information_type": " ".join , "Interface": " ".join , "Type_of_Interface": " ".join , "Connection_Mechanism": " ".join` to the above line in runtime.

It would be great if such a thing would be possible, else I would have to manually edit the column names and execute the `groupby` and `agg` operation for each table!

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this is what you want:

```
#setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0,5,25),
                   'b':np.random.randint(0,5,25),
                   'c':np.random.randint(0,5,25), 
                   'd':np.random.randint(0,5,25)}, dtype = str)

cols = ['b','c']

df.groupby('a').agg({col: " ".join for col in cols})
```

**Output**

```
               b              c
a                              
0  0 0 3 3 4 2 3  3 3 4 0 4 3 2
1      2 4 1 2 1      3 0 2 1 3
2        0 0 4 2        1 3 1 3
3    2 2 4 1 3 0    3 1 1 1 2 0
4          4 2 0          2 0 3
```